# Vue + Axios Post request response data returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, adonis.js

In my vue js project I have a services folder which handles with the interaction with the server. In my services folder I have a class that handles the authentication 
Auth.js

```
export default class Auth {
  login(email,password {
    let user = {email: email, password: password}
    axios.post("/login", user)
      .then(res => {
        return res.data
      })
  }
}
```

App.vue

```
  import Auth from './services/Auth'
  let auth = new Auth();
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null,
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }),
    methods: {
      login() {        
        let user = auth.login(this.email, this.password)
        console.log(user) // returns undefined
      }
    }
  }
```

for some reason the user is undefined, but when I check the network tab in chrome, I can see the user object returned when I send a post request to `/api/register` to my Adonis Application. Please help.

Comment: Assume that `axios.post` is asynс function, so you should use `await auth.login(this.email, this.password)` to get something in `console.log`

Comment: @AndrewShmig I modified, now the error is `await is a reserved keyword`, I added `async login(){..}` in my App.vue still returned undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed

Auth.js

```
export default class Auth {
    login(email,password {
        let user = {email: email, password: password}
        return axios.post("/login", user)
    }
}
```

App.vue

```
import Auth from './services/Auth'
let auth = new Auth();
export default {
    data: () => ({
        drawer: null,
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }),
    methods: {
        login() {        
            auth.login(this.email, this.password)
                .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        }
    }
}
```